# Printing out MySQL tables in HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am currently using the code below to print out a MySQL table. However, when I am printing multiple rows the format is pretty ugly. What is a way or command I could create columns similar to the Tab key to make it more aesthetically pleasing?

```
$google= mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($google)){
foreach($row as $cname => $cvalue){
    print "$cvalue\t <tr>";
}

print "<br>";
}
```

The query is printed using user input. using the

```
<form action="google.php" method="post">
```

command. I am also looking for a way to print this table on the same page as the HTML page that I accept the user input.

Comment: What have you researched so far?

Comment: this is as far as I have researched. I read something about a <tr> command but I am not sure I understand what it does.

Comment: http://www.quackit.com/html/html_table_tutorial.cfm

Comment: this doesn't really help me with a table that I have to wun a while loop for

Comment: You need to learn how to do it. I don't give out "magical answers". Fill in the blanks; place a table then put your variables in there. Start with an opening table tag, then your loop (in the middle), then the rest of your table code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is pretty good and only needs HTML added to it to make it look nicer.  Using tables (this has not been tested but it should work):

```
$google = mysqli_query($query) or die(mysqli_error());

echo '<table>';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($google)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($row as $cvalue) {
        print '<td>'.$cvalue.'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
```

This is a quick and dirty way to output a MySQL table, but if you also want the names of the columns to show up, things get quite a bit trickier.  Also, if your results contain special characters such as ">", this can mess up the output.  If that happens, just look up the documentation for `htmlspecialchars()`.

If you want this table to show up on the same page as your form, just create a submit button and check the value in PHP like so:

```
if (isset($_POST['SubmitButtonNameHere'])  { ... }
```

I'm not sure of the structure of your form so this code might need to be different to determine whether the form has been submitted.  You can put the code for creating the table inside of the curly braces and place the code for your form either above or below the if statement.

`<tr>` is an HTML element used to add rows to a `<table>` element.  The `<td>` element adds cells to those rows.  Also, your code was using `mysql_*`.  This was changed to `mysqli_*` as the mysql prefix is deprecated in PHP.  Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this code instead :)

```
$google= mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

echo "<table><tbody>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($google)){
foreach($row as $cname => $cvalue){
echo "<tr><td>".$cname."</td><td>".$cvalue."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</tbody></table>";
```

Done :)